# Output an env value in a js file

Tags: octobercms

I have a /.env file containing various environment settings for the site. I have a /themes/my-theme/assets/js/app.js file containing some JS code that runs on all pages. I want to output a value from the env file in the app.js file itself. To be clear I want to add a JS variable called timeout and assign it the value specified by the TIMEOUT setting in the .env file.

Any ideas on how to do this in October CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `.env` file to `root` and add your `variable and value`

> `.env` file content

```
TIMEOUT=3000
```

> Now in your `layout's code section` add this code

```php
function onStart()
{
    $this['env_timeout'] = env('TIMEOUT', '2000');
    // -----------  env var name - ^       ^ - default value    
}
```

[image]

> Now in your `layout's markup section` add this code

```
<script>var env_timeour = {{env_timeout}};</script>
```

[image]

> Now you can use it anywhere in your `js` just make sure you add `this script` `before your js file` so variable available to your `js file`

[image]

If you face any issue please comment.

Comment: Brilliant! It was the onStart() function I didn't know about.